# DB2 Store Procedure, What is a psm_pipe

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Why is there so little consistency in the DB2 documentation online?

I'm trying to create an SP that returns 4 values, it started out as a funky SQL statement with 'JOIN's and 'UNIONS' etc but has ended up as what will likely be a very inefficient SP..  And it still won't compile..!

Code as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Lex.LV_LogIn (
  -- Optional: input and output parameters
  --   { parameter-name } [IN | OUT | IN OUT] { data-type },
    IN LogIn VARCHAR(45),
    OUT RoleType BIGINT,
    OUT RoleDescription VARCHAR(45),
    OUT EmpName VARCHAR(45),
    OUT Granted BOOL
) 
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 
    DECLARE empid BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE usrid BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    SET RoleType = 0;
    SET RoleDescription = '';
    SET Granted = FALSE;

    SELECT "idCustEmployees", "idCustUserIds" INTO empid, usrid FROM LEX.CUSTUSERIDS WHERE "SourceType" = 'LexView' AND "LogIn" = LogIn;
    SELECT "idRoles" INTO RoleType FROM LEX.IDS2ROLES WHERE "idCustUserIds" = usrid;
    CASE
        WHEN RoleType > 0 THEN
            Granted = TRUE;
            SELECT "Description" INTO  RoleDescription FROM LEX.ROLES WHERE "idRoles" = RoleType;
            SELECT "FullName_C" INTO EmpName FROM LEX.CUSTEMPLOYEES WHERE "idCustEmployees" = empid;
        ELSE
            LEAVE;
    END CASE
END @
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE TO USER xxxxxxxxxx;
```

I've had error after error which is why I've broken it out into this crazy simple thing, before I tried CASE, I tried IF(...), IF(...)THEN and IF ... THEN...

All resulting in the same error:->
"psm_pipe" was expected instead of "CASE......

Question 1: What did I do wrong in the SP?

Question 2: What is psm_pipe and why doesn't come up if you google db2 "psm_pipe"?

Any ideas guys?

Thanks,
Bob B.

Comment: `Granted = TRUE; --> SET Granted = TRUE;`

Comment: `END CASE --> END CASE;`

Comment: LEAVE statement can be used in FOR, LOOP, REPEAT, or WHILE loops only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment has syntax mistakes. The code below will compile on Db2 Linux/Unix/Windows at version 11.1 or higher. The acronym PSM means Persistent Stored Module.

When asking for help, always write your Db2-server version and Db2-server operating-system (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) because answers vary per platform and version.

When you have syntax errors, always write the exact error-number (the SQLCODE and/or SQLSTATE), and the message, it is the sqlcode/sqlstate that is significant for searching.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Lex.LV_LogIn (
    IN LogIn VARCHAR(45),
    OUT RoleType BIGINT,
    OUT RoleDescription VARCHAR(45),
    OUT EmpName VARCHAR(45),
    OUT Granted BOOLEAN
)
LANGUAGE SQL
specific lv_login
BEGIN
    DECLARE empid BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE usrid BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    SET RoleType = 0;
    SET RoleDescription = '';
    SET Granted = FALSE;

    SELECT "idCustEmployees", "idCustUserIds"
    INTO empid, usrid
    FROM LEX.CUSTUSERIDS
    WHERE "SourceType" = 'LexView'
    AND "LogIn" = LogIn;

    SELECT "idRoles" INTO RoleType
    FROM LEX.IDS2ROLES
    WHERE "idCustUserIds" = usrid;

    IF RoleType > 0 THEN
        set Granted = TRUE;
        SELECT "Description"
        INTO  RoleDescription
        FROM LEX.ROLES
        WHERE "idRoles" = RoleType;

        SELECT "FullName_C"
        INTO EmpName
        FROM LEX.CUSTEMPLOYEES
        WHERE "idCustEmployees" = empid;
    END IF;
END @
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly :)
Thanks Mao, as far as I can see the key difference is the 'specific' keyword, is this required by default, because I only find it in about 50% of the SP examples..?

Comment: Done :)

Any idea on the psm_pipe?

Comment: Hi No sorry, I didn't keep a copy....
interestingly the psm_pipe was contained in a <> pair, but when I tried to paste it into the message, the complete object vanished.. even putting it in a ' ' didn't help.

Comment: `SPECIFIC` is not required. It is just useful when you have multiple procedures (or functions) with the same name but with a different number of input parameters or input parameters of a different type. It helps as e.g. when you want to drop the procedure in such a case, you don't have to list all the parameters to identified which version you want to drop

Comment: Also, if you used IBM Data Studio, that would syntax check as you type, and that makes it easier to spot syntax errors